# Php simple input to array

Tags: php, arrays, post, input, get

Recently I started with PHP and there's something im trying to find out.
This is what I want:

Input field + Submit. 
When u submit the form, the value of the input field goes in an array. lets say $array = array();
Every time you submit the value gets put in that array.

I've done things with $_GET and $_POST and other things like $_SESSION but I just can't get this to work..

Help would be appreciated! thanks!

EDIT: The information (list) will just be showed on the page. Not send to a mysql database or anything. When u refresh the page it would be gone.

Comment: You can either store it in a mysql database or serialize it and store it in the filesystem. Depends on how you're going to use the data later and many other things...

Comment: You can use a php session...or a js cookie....or the browser LocalStorage...even a text file ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep the data that you submitted.

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['a_value']))
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['a_value']) || !is_array($_SESSION['a_value']))
    {
        $_SESSION['a_value'] = array();
    }

    array_push($_SESSION['a_value'], $_POST['a_value']);
}

?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="a_value">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['a_value']))
{
    echo '<br><br>Values so far:<br><pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['a_value'], true).'</pre>';
}

?>
```

Comment: That is almost perfect! the only thing now was how I could get it to be like, submit 1, submit 2, etc. not  just the last one

Comment: I read your question again, please see the edit

Comment: This gives me a Fatal Error because of the [] on line 12! "[] operator not supported for strings"

Comment: That's weird, how about the new edit?

Comment: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given (string 12)..

Comment: Oops! try it again =)

Comment: You just made my day! This was exactly what I wanted! :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

there some better way for do this, but you can use the `session` like this:
you need 2 session variable for this aim, first for counting the array index, and second for value...
**here is an example**

```
    <form method="post" name="frm" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="submit">
    </form>

<?php
session_start();
    if ( isset($_POST['btn']) ) {
        $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
        $_SESSION['val'][$_SESSION['counter']] = $_POST['txt'];
        var_dump($_SESSION);    
    }
?>
```